# I subdivided the object now it's so big it makes my entire Macbook go into spinning rainbow

Tags: modeling, mesh

New to Blender

### Situation

I made an object in blender-, tried "subdivide" to see what it'd look like smoother and now it's too big (I think), now it slows down my whole Macbook, which can usually run 3 Adobe products simultaneously without slowdown.

### Tried

When I tired to un subdivide, I got a blocky mess, that's way less detailed than my original object.

### Question

How to unsubdivied to a lesser degree?

Comment: 1. Always save copies regularly! (Use Ctrl-Shift-S to Save as... and hit the '+' icon by the filename in the file selector to increase the filename before saving. In Blender 4+ you can use Ctrl-Alt-S - Save Incremental to do this automatically.)  2. Use a Subdiv Surface modifier rather than subdividing multiple times. Unsubdivide will not return your object to its original shape as you have found!

Comment: Oh darn-- okay! Thank you, Jason!!! I'll stop trying the same thing over and over and hoping it works!

Comment: Hi Sarah. Whenever asking, provide specific information(screenshots, Blender version, PC specs, type of object you subdivided), that might be useful to find a solution. This way you are more likely to find an answer suited for your purpose.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: This was my first post, thanks for letting me know, Edward :)

Answer (score 0):

Usually the modifier `Decimate` does a good job with `Un-Subdivide` when your high poly mesh has only quads.

Comment: Lukas--there's an actual "subdivide" option under decimate! Awesome! This is exactly what I needed--thank you!

Comment: if this answers your question, feel free to accept the answer